# Python Post json API without Request

Tags: python

I am on a system without pip and its not planned to use.
Put I have do to a post with python to an API (With this post I want to add a row in a postgresdb)

it works with the following code. but there are two columns which are jsonb in postgres.
With this code these columns have quotation marks, so the json doesn't work properly.

How can I avoid this?

```
  import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
def_post_wo_requ
        json_post= { 'store' : 'Jack', 'store_detail' : {'Tel1':'00000','Tel2':'11111'}}
        url=host+'/'+ pg_table
        data = urllib.parse.urlencode(json_post)
    
        data = data.encode('utf-8')
        print(data)
```

The print data shows this:

```
b'store=Jack&store_detail=%7B%27Tel1%27%3A+%2700000%27%2C+%27Tel2%27%3A+%2711111%27%7D'
```

and the json in the db is this:

```
"{'Tel1': '00000', 'Tel2': '11111'}"
```

Comment: You haven't made JSON data, you have converted a python dict to a string. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps ... also: show the code that is receiving the post request and inserting to the db

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to convert the data to a string?
Would not this ("classic" approach) work ?

```
from urllib import request
import json

url = 'https://myapp.domain/endpoint'
json_data= {'store': 'Jack', 'store_detail': {'Tel1': '00000','Tel2': '11111'}}

req = request.Request(url, method="POST")
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
data = json.dumps(data)
data = data.encode()
r = request.urlopen(req, data=data)
```